# Can we characterize the pairs of positive integers $b<a$ such that: $b|(a^2+\gcd(a,b))$

Tags: number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

Can we characterize the pairs of positive integers $b<a$ such that:

$b|(a^2+\gcd(a,b))$

Answer (score 1):

Let $d:=gcd(a,b)$, $a=da_0$ and $b=db_0$.

Then the condition given is $db_0|d^2a_0^2+d$. This is equivalent to $b_0|da_0^2+1$.

Comment: We also know $a^2 \ge b \ge gcd(a,b)$.

Comment: Sorry didn't see your edit.